# sip2sip.info SIP client: incoming RTP packets stop after 180 seconds

Tags: timeout, sip, rtp

I am running a SIP client (registered to **sip2sip.info**) on Ubuntu Linux 16.04. The client registers with the sip2sip.info correctly and accepts an incoming call. But, after exactly 180 seconds, the RTP stream from the sip2sip.info server stops. The **call remains active though**, with the client sending its RTP stream towards the server.

I observed that there was no RTP payload in the packets which are going out of the client (towards the server and the other party) and there was no RTCP. So, I tried to use 160 bytes of "0xff" as the payload and set the RTP marker to True, as well to check if I could overcome this issue.

But, the issue persists.
Also, I tried to use a client from iptel.org as well and faced the same issue.

**Any insights into this, will greatly help.**